# How do I cleanly uninstall the Left 4 Dead 2 Demo?

Tags: steam

Steam removed my access to the Left 4 Dead 2 Demo without warning. Now the game is sitting on my hard drive, useless, and it does not appear in my library for removal.

How do I remove this game?

Comment: Can't remember why I originally deleted this.

Comment: Did you solve your problem on your own?

Comment: @Raven Yep, I did.

Comment: Perhaps that's what moved you to delete it in the first place then.

Comment: @Raven Eh, I replied seconds after asking the question. A self-answer was entirely the point. Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steam has left a Left 4 Dead 2 Demo entry in the Control Panel, Add/Remove programs list. You can remove it from there.

---

Another method is manual removal, for when you know the game is still here, but doesn't appear in the Add/Remove programs list.

Just go to `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\` and remove all the LFD2 .ncf (they may not be .ncf, some steam games uses other archives files type).
Then, go to `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\'your account name'\` and delete the `lfd2` folder.

Sometimes, the `lfd2` folder seems to end in `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\`, it's an installation error.

Then, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues in the past uninstalling programs in such a state of limbo. If you end up having issues uninstalling a came like this, I'd recommend using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to do the uninstall.